# find number of groups assigned to a user

Tags: linux, active-directory

Is there a way to find the number of groups assigned to a user in linux?

```
 as of right now i have:
 foo : foo bar apple users
```

An app I use may have given a user a group of "apple users" but I cant tell and when i ran

```
 groups foo | awk {print $6}
```

I received

```
 users
```

I'm lost on how do find out how many users I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `groups` returns a list of groups your account is in, you can use the following:

`groups | wc -w`

The `wc -w` will count the number of words returned by `groups`.

Answer (score 1):

The groups command does not account for groups with spaces in its output.  So a group with a space in the name is output the same as two separate groups.

I would do it this way:

```
 grep "apple users" /etc/group
```

This should return something like

```
 apple users:x:1010:fred,barney,dino
```

Comment: Although I appreciate this answer, I had lookd in /etc/groups and "apple users" was not there. It is a group assigned by centrifydc. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Method-1:

foo : foo bar apple users (username -> foo)

run => lid foo | wc -l

Output : 4

Method-2:

run => groups username

Output : username : username group1 group2

=> groups username | wc -w | xargs -I % expr % - 2

Output : 3 (Number of groups that a user belongs to)

foo : foo bar apple users

run => groups foo | wc -w | xargs -I % expr % - 2

Output : 4

Count the number of words that groups  returns and subtract 2 as we have excess 'username' and ':' in the count we get. Finally we get the total number of groups that a user belongs to!